Create a runnable JAR manually by creating a zip file
I'm trying to create a runnable JavaFX JAR.
I have compiled all files (using Java 8, major version 52), creates a Manifest file and created a zip that contains these directories and files:
app.zip
META-INF
  MANIFEST.MF
lib
  javafx-controls.jar
  ...
animals
  Dog.class
  Cat.class
shapes
  Circle.class
  Square.class
controllers
  AllAnimalsController.class
views
  allanimals.fxml
Main.class

Then I renamed the zip into app.jar.
The lib folder contains all JavaFX dependencies. I can run the jar by doing this:
java --module-path lib  --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml   -jar app.jar 

But only if I run the jar from a directory that contains a lib folder:
running-jar-test-directory
  app.jar
  lib
    javafx-controls.jar
    ...

I can't make the jar run using its own lib folder (one packaged inside the jar), without relying on external lib folder located in running-jar-test-directory.
How do I accomplish it?
I tried updating my MANIFEST.MF to include all jar files in the lib folder like this:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/javafx-controls.jar ...
Main-Class: Main

But it didn't work - I get errors when trying to run the jar:
java   --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml   -jar app.jar 
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

java  -jar app.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

I know there are tools/plugins for creating the JavaFX jars, but I want to understand how to do it manually.

You can’t.  Not like this.  --module-path lib requires the presence of a lib directory.  Not an archive entry in a .jar file.  An actual directory.  However, if you want to make your application distributable, see here.

Why are you compiling with Java 8 if you then proceed to use Java 9+ features like a module-path? In any case, you can't zip up JAR dependencies inside the JAR with standard Java. You either need to create a fat-JAR, make a Java 9+ modular app, or use something like Spring Boot which provides a launcher which does allow you to zip JAR dependencies into the JAR (it uses a custom class loader to load those).

@VGR The question linked seems to be more concerned with web start, answers include making an exe file... I don't think that's what I need. I only need a simple jar that only I would use. It just should run without needing any dependencies outside the jar itself

The question is about Web Start, but Web Start is (sadly) discontinued.  My answer does not use Web Start at all.  I’m afraid you will have to create a jlink’d image, because JavaFX includes native libraries as well as Java classes.  You cannot distribute just JavaFX .jar files by themselves;  they need those native libraries.

I've looked around and noticed that other people's jars have a javafx folder in jar's root, with .class files inside packages. Perhaps, I should unpack all javafxjars that I have and copypaste their contents into a javafx folder in root of my jar? I'd really like to understand how it's done without plugins...


I'd really like to understand how it's done without plugin

Then follow the getting started documentation for creating a fat jar from the command line.
Section: Runtime Images | Non-modular project | Command Line.
Although link-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow, I won't reproduce the instructions here as they may become outdated and I don't want to maintain them.
Fat jars including JavaFX components are an unsupported runtime configuration for JavaFX applications.  If you get your application to run with such a configuration, it will output a warning to the console about an unsupported configuration. Nevertheless, if you correctly follow the steps it should work, at least with JavaFX 21.0.2.
I haven't tried the approach myself and don't recommend it (other options such as using build tools with plugins to package your application are preferred IMO).
Quoting the documentation:

you can also create a runnable fat jar for your JavaFX project on command line.
Warning: This is a discouraged tedious error-prone manual process that should be avoided by using the Maven's shade plugin or the Gradle's jar task, in case jlink is not applicable.
This JRE is platform-specific. However it can be easily a multi-platform jar if the different native libraries from each platform were included. This requires downloading the JavaFX SDKs for all the platforms, extracting all the necessary jars (for instance, javafx.graphics is different for each platform), and copying all the native libraries as shown above. As it was mentioned above, this process shouldn't be done manually.

